# Refresh Calendar.app with correct Exchange-account data

Tags: macos, calendar, exchange

In the Calendar.app on OS X I sync some calendars with an Exchange-account. When I look at the same calendar in Outlook all calendar items seems to be correct, but in the Calendar.app some items has the wrong date. I would like the Calendar.app to refresh so that it is equal to what I can see in the Outlook calendar, but normal Refresh does not help.

Are there any workaround that could fix such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was:

1. Open in Finder by running `open ~/Library/Calendars` in Terminal
2. Look for a folder that ends with `.exchange`. Open it.
3. Find the correct Exchange calendar by looking at the Info.plist files in each of the `.calendar` folders. Open the Events folder.
4. If you know that the problem is recent, sort all files by Date Modified. Set Cover Flow mode for showing the files in Finder
5. By looking at the items in Finder, Skip through the ics-files to search for the item that has the wrong date.
6. "Move to Trash" the incorrect item
7. Start the Calendar.app

I guess that it might be possible to "Move to trash" the `.calendar` folder for a full refresh of everything, but for me it was not necessary.

Comment: Do youknow where that folder is on modern systems?

Comment: @theonlygusti Could you please suggest what is a "modern system" to you? I have been using different systems, starting from Microsoft Basic on the Dragon32, so I would consider OS X as "modern" in that context. :)

Comment: I can't find the folder on macOS Monterey

Comment: @theonlygusti Ok. I currently also use macOS Monterey, and I get quite an extensive output if I open the Terminal.app, and then do a "find ~/Library/Calendars/*.exchange/*.calendar/Events/*.ics". Maybe these folders have survived on my system from an earlier exchange-implemenation that worked when I wrote this q&a.